# When can we add derivatives to both sides of an equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For example, we cannot add derivatives to $2x = 1$ which will lead to $2 = 0$.

But I found a solution like [this](https://paste.c-net.org/RecordedJules):

$$
\nabla_\sigma \xi_\rho = -\nabla_\rho \xi_\sigma \to \nabla_\mu \nabla_\sigma \xi_\rho = -\nabla_\mu \nabla_\rho \xi_\sigma
$$

($\xi$ is a killing vector)

I want to know if this operation is possible, Thanks!

Comment: You are not adding derivatives but taking derivatives.    In your $2x=1$ example, $x$ does not vary, so taking the derivative with respect to $x$ would be a strange thing to do.  But if you had $2x=y$ then it would be reasonable to say $2=\frac{dy}{dx}$.  The real difference in your question is that you are using "$=$" with two different meanings.

Comment: @Henry But we cannot say $f'(x) = 0$ from $f(x) = 0$? Or $f(x) = g(x) \to f'(x) = g'(x)$?

Comment: Differentiation acts on a function. For domain $x\in\mathbb R$, $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = 1$ are two different functions, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not always $=$.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "=" when you say "$f(x)=g(x)$".  If you take $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ then you can differentiate both sides and get $2x=1\times (x-1)+1\times (x+1)$ correctly.  If you take $2x=0$ then you cannot differentiate both sides together as you have changed the meaning of "$=$"